# Como utilizar cookies para autenticar em um API?

Tags: java, api, cookies

Estou com problema para efetuar a autenticação em uma API, a mesma gera um cookie após efetuar Login com usuário e senha, logo após, para efetuar um GET eu necessito   de enviar o cookie gerado.

Explicando detalhadamente:

Para logar com Curl

> curl -X POST -c /tmp/admincookies.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" -- insecure https://sd_wan_center_device_ip/sdwan_center/nitro/v1/config/login --data '{"login":{"username":"admin","password":"password"}}'

Consumindo

> curl -X GET -b /tmp/admincookies.txt --insecure "https://sd_wan_center_device_ip/sdwan_center/nitro/v1/reports/sites"

Agora preciso passar isto para Java:
Segue código:

```
String url = "https://IP_DO_DISP/sdwan_center/nitro/v1/config/login";
     HeadLog hea = new HeadLog();

     hea.login.setUsername("admin");
     hea.login.setPassword("senha");

     GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
     Gson gson = builder.create();
     System.out.println(gson.toJson(hea));

     RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
     ResponseEntity<String> headReturn = restTemplate.postForEntity(url,gson.toJson(hea) , String.class);

     HttpHeaders headers = headReturn.getHeaders();
     String set_cookie = headers.getFirst(headers.SET_COOKIE);

     System.out.println("Response: " + headReturn.toString() + "\n");
     System.out.println("Response: " + headReturn.getStatusCode() + "\n");
     System.out.println("Response: " + headReturn.getBody() + "\n");
     System.out.println("Set-Cookie: " + set_cookie + "\n");
     System.out.println("********* FINISH AUTH *******\n\n");
```

Resposta:

> {"login":{"username":"admin","password":"senha"}}
>   Response: 200 OK
>   Response: {"status":"success","user_level":"1","user_level_str":"admin","message":"Login Success - Created session for user admin - level: 1"}
>   Set-Cookie: COOKIE_NAME=value; expires=Wed, 30-Oct-2019 18:33:33 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
>   ********* FINISH AUTH *******

Consumindo com GET:

```
String urlWan_Links = "https://IP_DO_DISP/sdwan_center/nitro/v1/reports/sites";
     RestTemplate restTemplateDois = new RestTemplate();
     HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
     requestHeaders.add("Cookie",set_cookie);
     System.out.println("Request Header: "+ requestHeaders);
     HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(requestHeaders);
     System.out.println("Request Entity: " + requestEntity);
     ResponseEntity<String> response;
     try {           
         response = restTemplateDois.exchange(urlWan_Links, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
         System.out.println(response.getBody());
         System.out.println("\n Resposta: " + response);
     }
     catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Erro: "+ e);
     }
```

Resposta:

> Request Header: [Cookie:"COOKIE_NAME=value; expires=Wed, 30-Oct-2019 18:33:33 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly"]
>   Request Entity: <[Cookie:"COOKIE_NAME=value; expires=Wed, 30-Oct-2019 18:33:33 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly"]>
>   Erro: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized

Enfim, não estou achando solução....
Alguém poderia me dar uma mão?

Comment: Vc já tentou trabalhar com o padrão Factory? Dessa forma acredito que vc possa manter a mesma sessão

Comment: Não conheço, mas vou pesquisar sobre o assunto. Obrigado pela dica!!!

Comment: Atualiza aqui depois se tiver algum avanço

Comment: Agora entendi..... ele envia 3 set-cookies de volta, neste.. voce deve pegar o ultimo recebido, assim ele será a chave para futuras consultas....